# Why does the index get out of bounds in this program?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexoutofboundsexception

For some reason I get an error in python 2.7 when running this and entering in my 26 letter key. It says that the list index is out of range. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! (And I know I could've used a loop for the `encrypter`)

```
#-------------------------#
#     Code Translator     #
#-------------------------#

message = ''
messagearray = []
user = ''
encrypted = []
decrypted = []
keystring = ''
alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
dataset = []
keyarray = []

def encrypter():
    keystring = raw_input("Please paste key: ")
    message = raw_input("Message to Encrypt: ")

    for char in message:
        if char == alphabet[0]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[0])
        elif char == alphabet[1]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[1])
        elif char == alphabet[2]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[2])
        elif char == alphabet[3]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[3])
        elif char == alphabet[4]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[4])
        elif char == alphabet[5]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[5])
        elif char == alphabet[6]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[6])
        elif char == alphabet[7]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[7])
        elif char == alphabet[8]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[8])
        elif char == alphabet[9]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[9])
        elif char == alphabet[10]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[10])
        elif char == alphabet[11]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[11])
        elif char == alphabet[12]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[12])
        elif char == alphabet[13]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[13])
        elif char == alphabet[14]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[14])
        elif char == alphabet[15]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[15])
        elif char == alphabet[16]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[16])
        elif char == alphabet[17]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[17])
        elif char == alphabet[18]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[18])
        elif char == alphabet[19]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[19])
        elif char == alphabet[20]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[20])
        elif char == alphabet[21]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[21])
        elif char == alphabet[22]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[22])
        elif char == alphabet[23]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[23])
        elif char == alphabet[24]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[24])
        elif char == alphabet[25]:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[25])

    print ''.join(messagearray) 




def decrypter():
    keystring = raw_input("Please paste key: ")
    message = raw_input("Message to Decrypt: ")





def outputM():
    print decrypted

def userChoice():
    user = raw_input("Encrypt or Decrypt?")
    if user.upper() == "ENCRYPT":
        encrypter()
    elif user.upper() == "DECRYPT":
        decrypter()
    else:
        print "Please enter a valid command."
        userChoice()

for char in keystring:
    keyarray.append(char)

userChoice()
```

Here's the full traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 102, in <module>
    userChoice()
  File "translate.py", line 92, in userChoice
    encrypter()
  File "translate.py", line 43, in encrypter
    messagearray.append(keyarray[11])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what's the traceback?

Comment: Please: `import string; alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase`.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone , just posted. Thanks.

Comment: @Bakuriu just imported, next steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for char in keystring:
    keyarray.append(char)
```

`keystring` is empty so also keyarray will remain empty. In order not to have IndexError you would need a keystring as much longer as the alphabet (since basically you are just substituting chars)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for a while. I'll accept the answer as soon a the time limit goes away.

Comment: Looks like that was probably supposed to be part of decrypter()

Comment: Looks like. Indeed you should modify your code to always ask for a key, and then ask for decrypt or encrypt. You may also find interesting the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher (which is what you are trying to build, I guess)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in:

```
def decrypter():
    keystring = raw_input("Please paste key: ")
    message = raw_input("Message to Decrypt: ")
```

you are assigning the values to **local** variables, so the global ones remain empty. If you want to modify the global variables you have to state so:

```
def decrypter():
    global keystring, message
    keystring = raw_input("Please paste key: ")
    message = raw_input("Message to Decrypt: ")
```

the same is true for `encrypter`.

Also, you cannot create `keyarray` before having taken some input!

---

There are also many other issues with the code. You cannot possibly think that doing all the manual indexing is the best way to proceed. What if you want to support a 128 character alphabet?

Use loops:

```
for char in message:
    for i, c in enumerate(alphabet):
        if char == c:
            messagearray.append(keyarray[i])
```

(Instead of all those repeating lines).

Moreover strings already provide a method to do exactly what you are trying to do. It's called [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

You could simply do:

```
import string

table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, keystring)
```

And then use:

```
decrypted_text = some_encrypted_text.translate(table)
```

example run:

```
In [1]: import string
   ...: alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
   ...: table = str.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[3:]+alphabet[:3])
   ...: 

In [2]: 'hello'.translate(table)
Out[2]: 'khoor'
```

---

The above is for python3+. In python2.7 you have to use [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#string.maketrans) instead of `str.maketrans`. So you'd have to do:

```
In [1]: import string
   ...: alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
   ...: table = string.maketrans(alphabet, alphabet[3:]+alphabet[:3])
   ...: 

In [2]: 'hello'.translate(table)
Out[2]: 'khoor'
```

Comment: True, but it's also true that decrypter(), which should initialize the keystring, is not ensured to be executed, hence the keystring may stay empty also with the global variable declaration.